# What is the maximum allowed size of Mail?

Tags: iphone, email, attachment

I am making an application in which I am taking some information from user and send that information to an email account.In the email, I attach the following:

> **-About five images
>
>   - A ~5 minute audio file
>
>   - The message body**

Is it possible to send all the information in one email? What is the maximum message size?

If anyone has a better solution for it, please provide some source code or a demo for this.

Thanks to all

Comment: you'll probably have to determine the server's cap. often, the server would reject the message and provide an automated response stating that the message is too large.

Comment: Priyanka have you done your task? i have same requirement i want to know how did you send the mail having attachment more than 25 MB, so will you please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail doesn't have a limit, but an ISP would.  A realistic limit for most people is probably 10MB, though you may want to keep it more around 5MB and split things across emails...

Comment: if we compress those files then how can we handle size limit. how can we send the mail having attachment of more than 25 MB. Please suggest something if you know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have more than 10MB to send then I would send that data up to a server somewhere and email a link instead where they could get it.  Or, integrate the Dropbox API or iCloud API and have the data get transferred to other systems that way.  Email is a terrible, terrible way to send large amounts of data.